# Why is ANTLR not respecting the grammer order?

Tags: antlr4

In my grammer I have

```
zLine
  : Z fahrtnummer verwaltung takanzahl? taktZeitInMinuten? COMMENT ANYTHING NL
  ;

fahrtnummer
  : INT
  ;

verwaltung
  : ASCII
  ;
```

For input line like this

```
 *Z 00006 003849                                           % 00006 003849    00
```

`003849` is recognised as `INT` instead of `ASCII`. If I change the order of `INT` and ASCII in the lexer everything is recognised as `ASCII` which is wrong eiter. How can I make ANTLr respect the order given from the parser?

Full grammar

```
grammar FPLAN3;

fplan
  : zLine*;

zLine
  : Z fahrtnummer verwaltung takanzahl? taktZeitInMinuten? COMMENT ANYTHING NL
  ;

fahrtnummer
  : INT
  ;

verwaltung
  : ASCII
  ;

takanzahl
  : INT
  ;

taktZeitInMinuten
  : INT
  ;

Z: '*Z';

INT: [0-9]+;
ASCII: [0-9a-zA-Z]+;
//ASCII: [\P{Cc}\P{Cn}\P{Cs}]+;
COMMENT: '%';
ANYTHING: .*?;
NL: '\r'? '\n' | '\r';

IGNORE_SPACE
 : [ ] -> skip
 ;
```

Input File

```
*Z 00006 003849                                           % 00006 003849    00
*Z 00007 003849                                           % 00007 003849    00
*Z 00008 003849                                           % 00008 003849    00
```

Test rig output

```
[@0,0:1='*Z',<'*Z'>,1:0]
[@1,3:7='00006',<INT>,1:3]
[@2,9:14='003849',<INT>,1:9]
[@3,58:58='%',<'%'>,1:58]
[@4,60:64='00006',<INT>,1:60]
[@5,66:71='003849',<INT>,1:66]
[@6,76:77='00',<INT>,1:76]
[@7,78:79='\r\n',<NL>,1:78]
[@8,80:81='*Z',<'*Z'>,2:0]
[@9,83:87='00007',<INT>,2:3]
[@10,89:94='003849',<INT>,2:9]
[@11,138:138='%',<'%'>,2:58]
[@12,140:144='00007',<INT>,2:60]
[@13,146:151='003849',<INT>,2:66]
[@14,156:157='00',<INT>,2:76]
[@15,158:159='\r\n',<NL>,2:78]
[@16,160:161='*Z',<'*Z'>,3:0]
[@17,163:167='00008',<INT>,3:3]
[@18,169:174='003849',<INT>,3:9]
[@19,218:218='%',<'%'>,3:58]
[@20,220:224='00008',<INT>,3:60]
[@21,226:231='003849',<INT>,3:66]
[@22,236:237='00',<INT>,3:76]
[@23,238:237='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:78]
line 1:9 missing ASCII at '003849'
line 1:60 mismatched input '00006' expecting ANYTHING
line 2:9 missing ASCII at '003849'
line 2:60 mismatched input '00007' expecting ANYTHING
line 3:9 missing ASCII at '003849'
line 3:60 mismatched input '00008' expecting ANYTHING
(fplan (zLine *Z (fahrtnummer 00006) (verwaltung <missing ASCII>) (takanzahl 003849) % 00006 003849 00 \r\n) (zLine *Z (fahrtnummer 00007) (verwaltung <missing ASCII>) (takanzahl 003849) % 00007 003849 00 \r\n) (zLine *Z (fahrtnummer 00008) (verwaltung <missing ASCII>) (takanzahl 003849) % 00008 003849 00))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parser rules have no impact on Lexer rule evaluation.

During the flexing phase all rules are evaluated against the input stream of characters. If multiple rules match the following come into play.

1 - if a rule matches a longer sequence of input characters the Lexer will produce a token for that rule.
2 - If multiple rules match sequences of the same length, then the first lexer rule will be used to generate the token.

since `INT` and `ASCII` can both match a sequence of digits, then the lexer will produce a token for whichever appears first in the grammar.

Note, while the parser is recursive descent, it runs against the token stream, so all tokens are determined before the parser has any involvement.  It won't matter which parser rule path you follow, the token type has already been determined.  In short, the Lexer can't "respect the order given from the parser".  The parser acts on the output of the Lexer.